# AND function with two ISNUMBER SEARCHES

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to write a formula that is uses two `ISNUMBER` `SEARCH`ES, if two then returns "4909 Billable".

This is what I have so far:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ECI",O2))),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CASES BY",U2)),"4509 Not Billable","")
```

But it's not working

Comment: David Dai, seems to have corrected your syntax errors. It's assumed that the rest of your formula is done in the correct manner. If the solution works out, please click the green check mark for completion and acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your formula:
1. Not matching parenthesis: an extra `)` before the 1st `,`  which should be before the 2nd `,`
2. Not referring to cells properly, you should use `$O2` instead of just `O2`

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ECI",$O2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CASES BY",$U2))),"4509 Not Billable","")
```